# C++17 interfaces usage by C++14 application

Tags: c++, linux, interface, c++17, c++14

I have an application(my app) which is strictly developed with C++14 std. and there is a new library which is supplied by a third party and it has c++17 interfaces. How can I make use of this C++17 interfaces in my c++14 application? (Strictly myapp do not want to use any c++17 features).

Do we need a wrapper to handle the c++17 interface? so that my application(myapp) do not have to use any c++17 features.

Comment: (a) you will need to wrap it; and (b) be careful about ABI compatibility as depending on your tool-chain the standard library data structures may not be binary compatible between C++14 and C++17.

Comment: @RichardCritten I am not aware of any changes with C++17 that require an ABI break or any break in a standard library implementation when C++17 instead of C++14 is chosen.

Comment: @uss Is there any reason not to simply switch to C++17 for the app? There should be almost no breaking changes between C++14 and C++17. Specifically they are listed [here](https://www.eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp14).

Comment: @user17732522, I wish the same. But due to project restrictions I am unable to. To explain further, we are using Adaptive Autosar standard and  it enforces us to use only C++14.

Comment: @uss But then if you write a wrapper that understands C++17-only features and therefore must itself be compiled with C++17 enabled, would that be in compliance?

Comment: @user17732522 I agree, but I think it's always a good idea to check with the tool-chain documentation and not assume.

Comment: If Adaptive Autosar is some industry-specific certification thing, third party libraries probably also have to adhere to it. If not, did you check if the library has a C++14 version or a C version you can wrap or if a different third party is providing a C++14 version?

Comment: What could be a better approach for a wrapper?